# Association bonus bug

Tags: bug, reputation, profile-page

Is there a known bug about updating the rep-score after receiving the association bonus? (If the first picture is not clear it says 412 at the top of the graph about rep.)

[image: stackechange]

On the other sites (where I definitively do not deserve the points) the update has been immediate
[image: mathoverflow]

**update: My rep has now been updated.**

Comment: You do "deserve the bonus" in other groups, in the sense that you have demonstrated the maturity to handle the privileges granted to users with 100 rep no matter which group you're in.

Comment: If you are a trusted user in any SE group, and you join a new group for the first time, then you get +100 in that group immediately.  So you only have to figure out how SE groups work, and go through the effort that will get you from rep 1 to rep 100 once.  After that, it is automatic in any new group you join.  [A reason to join groups, not merely visit them without joining.]  Spammers cannot just jump in and post whatever they want, since their rep will be only 1.

Comment: @GEdgar You probably meant to say "from rep 1 to rep 200" rather than rep 100 - the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/association-bonus/info) is awarded to user who have at least 200 reputation points on some site. (Anyway, this seems to be digression from what this question is actually asking.)